# What is the appropriate pronunciation of the "dmesg" filename?

Tags: dmesg

How should the file `dmesg` (as in `/var/log/dmesg`) be pronounced?  I've always pronounced it as "dee message" but received an odd reaction from a Unix admin when I did that.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: If the pronunciation carries with it an unmistakable pointer to the file being referenced, then it is a valid pronunciation.

Comment: An "odd reaction" from a Unix admin on *any* topic is not really unusual.

Comment: If this is too subjective, let me know and we can close it out.  Meta conversation: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-how-to-pronounce-commands

Comment: May be look up dmesg on youtube.

Comment: I've always pronounced it "dee message" - it seems perfectly appropriate.

Comment: I looked through the first ~20 videos on a youtube search for "dmesg". Of the 4 that had speech, they all pronounced it "dee message".

Comment: Perhaps you could set up 2 (or more) answers, each with a proposed pronunciation, and we could each upvote the one we use, giving you a poll.

Comment: Been administering Unix for about 25 years, I've always called it "dee message". How did the admin with the odd reaction say it should be pronounced?